# Using environment variable as a python argument fails in Makefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, environment-variables

I have a Makefile with this target:

```
MY_DIR:=${CURDIR}/MY/DIR
my_proj: 
    cd $(MY_DIR); echo $(MY_ENV_VAR); python $(MY_ENV_VAR)/myscript.py --src $(MY_DIR) config
```

that runs a python script, i.e. `myscript.py` that its location is stored in the `MY_ENV_VAR` environment variable. The weird point is that the echo command, prints the variable correctly (i.e. c:/my/project/dir), but the python complains that it cannot find the script file with this error:

```
python.exe: can't open file 'c:myprojectdir/myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Now, the main Q is why the make tool interprets my environment variable correctly in the echo command, but the path is broken while passing to python?

p.s. I am working with python 3.7.3, make 4.2.1 on Windows 10.

**Update 1:** I have used the `$(value ...)` function as described in some other questions and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Value-Function), but the problem is still the same.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $(MY_ENV_VAR)`?

Comment: @Sraw, oops, it is C:\my\project\dir

Comment: Um, as @Vorpal says, it doesn't seem to be a correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information given it is hard to know. I would guess that perhaps you have c:\ instead of c:/ in that path and that the \ end up as an invalid escape character. Try using \\ in the path, or replacing it with a forward slash.

I can't test this myself though since I'm on Linux.